# Using void pointer to simulate a generic linkedlist in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, void-pointers, c11

I'm new to C, and I think there may be an issue with pointers here. Any help would be appreciated!

I have a linkedlist struct that looks like this:

ll.h:

```
#ifndef LLTEST_LL_H
#define LLTEST_LL_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _listNode {
    void *data;
    struct _listNode *next;
} listNode;

typedef struct {
    int logicalLength;
    int elementSize;
    listNode *head;
    listNode *tail;
} linkedlist;

typedef struct table {
    const char* name;
    size_t col_count;
    size_t length;
} table;

typedef struct db {
    const char* name;
    size_t table_count;
    table** tables;
} db;

void list_append(linkedlist *list, void *element);
void create_list(linkedlist *list, int elementSize);
void create_db(const char* db_name, db** db);

#endif //LLTEST_LL_H
```

main.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ll.h"

linkedlist databases_list;

void create_list(linkedlist *list, int elementSize)
{
    list->logicalLength = 0;
    list->elementSize = elementSize;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
}

void list_append(linkedlist *list, void *element)
{
    listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    node->data = malloc(list->elementSize);
    node->next = NULL;
    memcpy(node->data, element, list->elementSize);

    if(list->logicalLength == 0) {
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    list->logicalLength++;
}

listNode* find_database_node(char *name){

    listNode *node = databases_list.head;
    //bool result = true;
    listNode *found_node = NULL;

    while(node != NULL) {
        db *item = (db *)node->data;

        if (strcmp(item->name, name) == 0){
            found_node = node;
            break;
        }

        node = node->next;
    }

    return found_node;
}

void get_db_pool(char *name, db *value){
    listNode *node = find_database_node(name);

    if(node != NULL){
        value = (db *)node->data;
    }
    else{
        value = NULL;
    }
}

void set_db_pool(db* value){
    list_append(&databases_list, (void *)value);
}

void create_db(const char* db_name, db** db) {
    if (*db == NULL) {
        *db = malloc(sizeof(db));
    }

    (*db)->name = db_name;
    (*db)->table_count = 0;
    (*db)->tables = NULL;
}

int main() {

    create_list(&databases_list, sizeof(db *));
    char* db_name= "mydb";
    db* db1 = NULL;
    create_db(db_name, &db1);
    set_db_pool(db1); //<--this line

    return 0;
}
```

On the line that I have marked "<--this line", when I check (db)databases_list.head->data's name parameter, I see "\222\017" instead of "mydb" as I would expect (such as when I check db1->name). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  We prefer to see compilable code — and the header shown won't compile because you have `listNode *` elements in your `linkedList` structure before you've said what a `listNode` is.  Please show the real code if it is compiling, and if it isn't compiling, you should be asking about the compilation errors, not runtime errors as you seem to be.

Comment: Note that you are treading on thin ice with the `struct _listNode` tag name.  Names starting with an underscore are basically reserved for the implementation to use.  The full details are a bit more nuanced than that, but it is not a gross overstatement and is a lot simpler to state than the nuanced rules.  Most of the time, you'll get away with using such names, but there are no guarantees that you'll always do so.  Tread carefully.

Comment: Debugging code is a valuable skill you should learn if you intend to continue programming. I'm not saying you haven't invested effort into figuring out what's wrong with your code. But, stackoverflow is not meant as a debugging tool (though it is a great resource to use while you debug). If you have a concrete question about why some particular snippet of code is not working as expected, then that would be a more appropriate question. I recommend isolating the line(s), or at least the function(s) in which things begin to go awry. I guarantee you'll better understand your code after doing so.

Comment: There are pointers inside your `db` struct. When you `memcpy` one, both the original and the copy point to the same things. Who owns the pointed-to objects?

Comment: I updated to be a more simple/compilable file. @JonathanLeffler I appreciate your thoughts on the underscore tagname. I'll rework that.

Comment: @hexturtle I didn't say I was new to programming... but new to C. No worries in any case, I'm not offended. Also, I wasn't asking to debug the code... I have a specific question (because I don't understand the behavior), but I think your point is valid... It's more concise now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the revised code and edited a bit to suit some of my prejudices, so my line numbers are probably slightly different from yours.  When I run it under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/), I get a complaint:

```
==55831== Invalid write of size 8
==55831==    at 0x100000EC7: main (ll17.c:78)
==55831==  Address 0x100a7c350 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==55831==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==55831==    by 0x100000EB9: main (ll17.c:73)
==55831== 
==55831== Invalid write of size 8
==55831==    at 0x100000ECF: main (ll17.c:78)
==55831==  Address 0x100a7c348 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==55831==    at 0x1000066F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==55831==    by 0x100000EB9: main (ll17.c:73)
```

Line 73 is as shown:

```
void create_db(const char* db_name, db** db) {
    if (*db == NULL) {
        *db = malloc(sizeof(db));  // 73
    }
```

This allocates enough space for a pointer (strictly, a pointer to a pointer), not for a `db` structure.

- **You should avoid using variables with the same name as their (base) type — it confuses everyone except the compiler.**

You really need:

```
void create_db(const char* db_name, db** db) {
    if (*db == NULL) {
        *db = malloc(sizeof(**db));
    }
```

With that change in place, the code runs OK under `valgrind`. According to my build of `valgrind`, it leaks a lot, but I've recently upgraded from Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite to 10.11 El Capitan, and I don't trust my suppressions file to give me any useful information.  It was built under Yosemite, and I'm also getting 'unknown `fcntl` calls' tracked by `valgrind`.

Comment: Thanks! looks like you're right. To be honest, I'm not sure why that needs to be a pointer to a pointer... it and the db and table structs were part of the boilerplate given in the class I'm taking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line int your test code right here might be flawed.

```
create_list(&databases_list, sizeof(db *), NULL);
```

when you do sizeof(db *) you are actually getting the size of the pointer NOT the db struct.  You should actually be doing sizeof(db).  Since the element size only gets set to the size of a pointer you don't copy enough data over and when you read back you read corrupted data from memory causing your incorrect values.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I tried both ways, and it doesn't seem to behave any differently.