# C LinkedList storing the last value only

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having problem storing all the values into the Generic LinkedList, my linkedlist works totally works on a normal user Keyboard input but when I try to store values(strings) from a file, there is something weird happening, it only store the last value of the file.

I have checked my addToList() function but theres nothing wrong with it.

P.s But I am feeling its either I am printing wrong or my reading from the file into the linkedlist is wrong.

Thank you.

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "LinkedListItems.h"
#define MAX 10000

int main()
{
    printf("Testing MissileFIle.txt");

    void* secondStr;
    //Had to malloc the thing 
    secondStr = (void*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    FILE* missileFile;
    missileFile = fopen("missiles.txt", "r");

    if(missileFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file is empty");
    }    

    number_list_t* missileList = calloc(1, sizeof(number_list_t));

    void* input;

    //Have to allocate the input 
    input = malloc(1*sizeof(void*));

    //this is to read the data into the second Str
    while(fgets(secondStr,MAX,missileFile) != NULL)
    {
        //Let just print out first just to test my memory
        printf("%s\n",secondStr);
        //Right now its only reading one string so far which is really weird AFFFFF
        addTolist(missileList,secondStr);

    }

    //Gotta declare another list just to print out the list 
    number_node_t* current = missileList->head; 


    while(current != NULL)
    {
        //There is something wrong with this line
        printf("%s\n",current-> number);
        current = current-> next; 
    }
    fclose(missileFile);



}
```

OUTPUT: 
Testing MissileFile.txt

splash

single

V-line

h-line

Single
Single
Single
Single
Single
Single

```
typedef struct NumberNode 
{
    //It can store any data type 
    void* number;
    struct NumberNode* next; 
}number_node_t;


//List of Nodes 
typedef struct NumberList 
{
    number_node_t* head; 
    int count; //This is not nesssary but it can be useful for counting how  many variables 

}number_list_t;




       void addTolist(number_list_t* list, void* newNumber)
    {
        //tem[ = newNode]
        number_node_t* newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(number_node_t));
        newNode->number = newNumber; 
        newNode->next = list->head;
        list->head = newNode;
    }
```

INPUT DATA: 
single
splash
single
V-Line
h-line
Single

Comment: `newNode->number = newNumber;` copies the   pointer, not the string.

Comment: Yea but how is that effect the reading of the last element only

Comment: `secondStr = (void*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));` This is the first of several problems.

Comment: if I remove that line it still show me the same output, doesnt really change anything

Comment: @Obamaself Don't ignore the compiler warnings, those tend to bite you back later.

Comment: Code is reading every element into the same buffer and then it saves the address of that same buffer.-   only the last string in the buffer is printed

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that totally make sense, how can i not repeat into the same buffer if i may ask.

Comment: the posted code includes the home grown header file: `LinkedListItems.h`  However, the contents of that header file are missing from the OPs question.  This makes reproducing the problem VERY difficult.  Please post the contents of that header file

Comment: OT: regarding; `number_node_t* newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(number_node_t));`   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to pass both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: regarding: `void* input;

    //Have to allocate the input 
    input = malloc(1*sizeof(void*));`  This heap allocation is never used and the code fails to pass the pointer to `free()` before exiting.  The result is a compiler warning and a memory leak

Comment: regarding: *how can i not repeat into the same buffer*  Suggest reading into a single buffer, but calling `strdup()` when placing into the linked list node

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(secondStr,MAX,missileFile) != NULL)`  Remember that `fgets()` includes the trailing newline in the input buffer.  Most likely you want to not keep that newline.  A simple/reliable way to remove the newline is: `secondStr[ strcspn( secondStr, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `number_node_t* newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(number_node_t));`  for each entry another heap memory allocation is made, but those memory allocations are never passed to `free()` before the program exits.  The result is LOTS of memory leaks.  Suggest using `valgrind` to find all the memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented this, it cannot work.

The main problem, among many, is related to the `void*` pointers which cannot be dereferenced. 
The size of elements should be given, either on creating the list in which case all elements are of the same type, or separately for each individual element. You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061335/using-void-pointer-to-simulate-a-generic-linkedlist-in-c) question for an example of something that could work.

As far as the buffer thing is concerned, `addToList` should allocate new memory for each `newNumber`. What you are currently doing results in all data of the list pointing to a specific space in memory (the one allocated to `secondStr`). Each time you change the content of that memory space, all elements in the list are affected. This is why you print the same value for all elements and more specifically the last value in your file.

The way you allocate memory is also not really ok, same goes for the way you open your file, there is memory leaking etc. I am not going into details.

Answer (score 0):

At *least* this issue:

**Copy the string**

OP's goal includes the need to copy the string from the read buffer to the list, not just copy the buffer pointer.

```
// void addTolist(number_list_t* list, void* newNumber) {
void addStringTolist(number_list_t* list, const char *s) {
    // number_node_t* newNode = calloc(1,sizeof(number_node_t));
    number_node_t* newNode = calloc(1, sizeof *newNode); // todo: add error check
    size_t sz = strlen(s) + 1;
    newNode->number = malloc(sz);  // todo: add error check
    strpy(newNode->number, s);   
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
}
```

Note: When freeing the list, `newNode->number` also needs to be free'd.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
while(fgets(secondStr,MAX,missileFile) != NULL)
```

MAX is defined as 10000 but `secondStr` is defined as pointer to one byte.  so when this is executed, a buffer overflow occurs.

This is undefined behavior and probably the root of the problem with reading from a file